# Fast complex absolute argmax in Cython

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I'm thinking I implemented it optimally, but somehow it's much slower than what *should be* much slower, `np.argmax(np.abs(x))`. Where am I off?

#### Code rationale & results

- Mathematically, `abs` is `sqrt(real**2 + imag**2)`, but `argmax(abs(x)) == argmax(abs(x)**2)`, so no need for square root
- `np.abs(x)` also allocates and writes an array. Instead I overwrite a single value, `current_abs2`, which should eliminate allocation and only leave writing
- Argmax logic should be identical to NumPy's (I've not checked but only one best way to do it?)
- Views (`R`, `I`) are for... I don't recall, saw somewhere

So savings are in dropping `sqrt` and `len(x)`-sized allocation. Yet it's much slower...

```py
%timeit np.argmax(np.abs(x))
%timeit abs_argmax(x.real, x.imag)
```

```
409  µs ± 2.33 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
3.09 ms ± 14.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Here's the [generated C code](https://pastebin.com/BnddTibD), just the function; the whole `_optimized.c` is 26000 lines.

The following [Numba](https://pastebin.com/A6hPwWEE) achieves `108 µs`, very satisfactory, though I'm interested in why Cython fails.

#### Code

```
import cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cpdef int abs_argmax(double[:] re, double[:] im):
    # initialize variables
    cdef Py_ssize_t N = re.shape[0]
    cdef double[:] R = re  # view
    cdef double[:] I = im  # view

    cdef Py_ssize_t i = 0
    cdef int max_idx = 0
    cdef double current_max = 0
    cdef double current_abs2 = 0

    # main loop
    while i < N:
        current_abs2 = R[i]**2 + I[i]**2
        if current_abs2 > current_max:
            max_idx = i
            current_max = current_abs2
        i += 1

    # return
    return max_idx
```

#### Setup & execution

I use `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`, `setup.py` shown at bottom. Then,

```py
import numpy as np
from _optimized import abs_argmax

x = np.random.randn(100000) + 1j*np.random.randn(100000)
%timeit np.argmax(np.abs(x))
%timeit abs_argmax(x.real, x.imag)
```

`setup.py` (I forget the rationale, just took certain recommendations)

```py
from distutils import _msvccompiler
_msvccompiler.PLAT_TO_VCVARS['win-amd64'] = 'amd64'

from setuptools import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy as np

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize(Extension("_optimized", ["_optimized.pyx"]),
                          language_level=3),
    include_dirs=[np.get_include()],
)
```

#### Environment

Windows 11, i7-13700HX CPU, Python 3.11.4, Cython 3.0.0, setuptools 68.0.0, numpy 1.24.4

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  It's best to describe **what value this code provides to its user**.

Comment: Don’t `while i < N; i += 1`. Use a proper for loop, which can benefit from loop unrolling and other compiler optimizations. I presume your build is an optimized build, but I don’t know how Cython builds by default. Double-check that.

Comment: Are you sure `cdef double[:] R = re` is not a copy? Why do you need this anyway? Doesn’t `x.real, x.imag` create copies too?

Comment: Thanks @CrisLuengo - I dunno what the views are for, seen them earlier and assume it's for the best (they don't copy, and certainly not `x.real` `x.imag` (poor MATLAB?)). Also just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40775661/10133797). I don't recall what's up with the while, again I have some precedent from months ago. I tested both your suggestions, they didn't help, but the code is certainly cleaner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a generated code (slightly edited for readability)

```
__pyx_v_current_abs2 = (
    pow((*((double *) ((__pyx_v_R.data + __pyx_t_2 * __pyx_v_R.strides[0]) ))), 2.0) +
    pow((*((double *) ((__pyx_v_I.data + __pyx_t_3 * __pyx_v_I.strides[0]) ))), 2.0)
);
```

I do not like calls to `pow`. Apparently, [cython](/questions/tagged/cython) is not smart enough, and transpiles `** 2` into a function call, rather that a simple multiplication. Try to help it:ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

```
    current_abs2 = R[i]*R[i] + I[i]*I[i]
```

and see what happens. As of the rest - failed branch predictions, missed vectorization, etc - we may only theorize.

Answer (score 3):

The OP code suffers from at least a 6x factor of suckage.
The question would benefit from posting
[godbolt](https://godbolt.org)
links which examine the differences in the generated code.

Often the trouble boils down to

- inability to vectorize
- poor branch prediction

```
        if current_abs2 > current_max:
```

It seems plausible that branch prediction
is falling apart there.

Consider pre-computing a bunch of `abs2` values,
sorting them descending, and returning the zeroth element.
It's O(N log N), so theoretically worse by a factor of log N.
But it might interact with memory hierarchy better in practice.
Bench, and [report back](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: I don't know if branch prediction-based improvement is possible, the data is randomized. Sorting is surely much slower than argmax, and not just per log N. Vectorization, perhaps, though should be up to x4 difference on single core from what I've read. I don't know how to make godbolt work but I added a C excerpt.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [vnp's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/286209/210581); here's `np.argmax(np.abs(x))` vs Numba vs Cython:

```
414  µs ± 8.09 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000  loops each)
89.9 µs ± 1.2  µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
66.8 µs ± 1.11 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

#### Code

```
import cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cpdef int abs_argmax(double[:] R, double[:] I):
    # initialize variables
    cdef Py_ssize_t N = R.shape[0]

    cdef Py_ssize_t i = 0
    cdef int max_idx = 0
    cdef double current_max = 0
    cdef double current_abs2 = 0

    # main loop
    for i in range(N):
        current_abs2 = R[i]*R[i] + I[i]*I[i]
        if current_abs2 > current_max:
            max_idx = i
            current_max = current_abs2

    return max_idx
```